# Why do I get a syntax error from PostgreSQL when trying to dynamically add columns to a table?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have any values in list:

`list = ['hostname', 'ip-address', 'public-ip-address']`

I need to alter table adding new columns if not exists in list.

Is possible add the new colun in query PostgreSQL?  I'm trying...

```
def alter_table_system(self, keys: list[str]):
    try:
        fields = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(keys))
        alter_table = "ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_pa_system ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS (%s)" %(fields)
        self.cursor.execute(alter_table)
        self.conn.commit()
    except(Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print(error)
```

How can verify the actual table and columns, and add a new columns in list?

I receive the error:

```
syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ... IF EXISTS tbl_pa_system ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS (%s, %s, %...
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: Hint: does that query in the error look like how you want it to be?

Comment: There are many things wrong with this 1) The `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN` does not take a list of columns per [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) 2) You are doing string interpolation for parameter passing which is a SQL injection issue see [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) 3) If you want to do dynamic SQL use  the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html)

Comment: I'm new to Python and BD.  I'm using psycopg2..  I'm trying: alter_table = """ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_pa_system ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS (%s) TEXT;""",(element)

It's in for element in list.. But i get this error: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead.     

And only execute one time..

Comment: Hint, you cannot use `%s` for object identifiers.  Read this link [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) I posted earlier, it will take you through the process of building dynamic SQL.

Comment: Finnally it worked !  I do in this form.. 

```for i in range(0,len(new_columns)):
        q3 = sql.SQL("ALTER TABLE tbl_teste ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS {} TEXT").format(
            sql.SQL(', ').join([sql.Identifier(new_columns[i])]))
        cursor.execute(q3)
        conn.commit()```

Comment: FYI, if `new_columns` is a list then it can be shortened to, `for col in new_columns ...[sql.Identifier(col)]`.